# Converting cgs to 'custom' units in Astropy

Tags: python, astropy, units-of-measurement, unit-conversion

I have the following

```
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.modeling.models import BlackBody

bb = BlackBody(temperature=303.15*u.K)
wav = np.arange(1.0, 50.0) * u.micron
flux = bb(wav)
```

where flux has units:

```
 erg / (cm2 Hz s sr)
```

I'd like to convert these to:

```
 W / (m2 sr Hz)
```

but simply doing

```
flux.si
```

gives  `flux` but with 10^-3 values and units of kg / (rad2 s2).

Answer (score 0):

```
flux.to(u.W/u.m**2/u.steradian/u.Hz)
```

seems to do the trick nicely.